# why changing fillStyle in canvas 2D changes the color of previously drawn rectangles?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following code that first draws 3 small yellow rectangles and then draws a big blue one. I change fillStyle property before the last drawing. As a result, all rectangles are blue.
If the last drawing is not performed (ctx.fill is commented out in the second loop), then I see 3 yellow rectangles.

```js
const get = id => document.getElementById(id);

const canv = get('canv');
const [w, h] = [canv.width, canv.height];
const ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  ctx.rect(10*x, 100, 3, 3);
  ctx.fill();
}

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
for (let x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
  ctx.rect(10*x + 100, 100, 5, 5);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #020408;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="200" height="200" style="border: solid 1px grey"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concerns the [current default path](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#current-default-path) of the canvas. There is *only one*. As you do not close one path and begin another, the *entire path* (i.e. both sets of rectangles) is rendered in blue.

Just the first part of the path looks like

```js
const get = id => document.getElementById(id);

const canv = get('canv');
const [w, h] = [canv.width, canv.height];
const ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  ctx.rect(10*x, 100, 3, 3);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #020408;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="200" height="200" style="border: solid 1px grey"></canvas>
```

Adding `beginPath` solves the problem.

```js
const get = id => document.getElementById(id);

const canv = get('canv');
const [w, h] = [canv.width, canv.height];
const ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  ctx.rect(10*x, 100, 3, 3);
  ctx.fill();
}
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
for (let x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
  ctx.rect(10*x + 100, 100, 5, 5);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #020408;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="200" height="200" style="border: solid 1px grey"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got confused here, probably should've used  ctx.fillRect() instead